# Would a public DNS help secure downloads over an unsecure connection?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I am downloading large files with their checksums/hashes on a Linux machine with the DNS manually setup to use a publicly available trusted DNS, e.g., Google's 8.8.8.8 since I am aware that DNS can be spoofed to possibly host a compromised version of the files as well as the corresponding checksums/hashes.
If I were to download the software over a connection I suspect may be compromised, e.g., infected router or cell basestation operated by a malicious third-party, would verifying the files using the checksums/hashes be enough to ensure that the files I downloaded were not compromised in any way?
Are there any ways an attacker could compromise the download in this setup?
Naturally, I will be downloading over HTTPS, but does that make a difference here?

Comment: You mean like an attacker altering the user's DNS settings or intercepting the query and responding on-behalf-of with a fake hash/op so that the user downloads the file from a dodgy server and verifies the dodgy version to be ok using the fake hash?

Comment: If you could expound on these further, and maybe write an answer based on it, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question about the security of downloaded files.

So, where do you download from? In the simplest form, you download a file from a URL. The hostname will be translated to an IP address. There are a number of measures to make sure that you connect to the right host:

- use Google DNS (weak, but less easy to fake than a local DNS)
- use DNSSEC
- use hard IP addresses instead of hostnames
- etc.

HTTPS does two things:

- it authenticates the connection
- it encrypts the connection

So yes, using https helps.

Whether checksum or hashes help depends a lot on what you use. A simple MD5 hash is sufficient to determine whether a file transfer has been correctly, but offers little resistance to a malicious attacker. If you need to be absolutely sure, use SHA-2 and have the file signed.

Another way would be to use an encrypted VPN, either directly to the file provider or to a trusted location from where a less dodgy Internet connection is available.

If it is publicly available (f.e. Linux packages), you may consider downloading them from multiple sources and comparing the results.

And the final recommendation is, if your Internet connection is not to be trusted, don't use it for such critical files; invest some time and money in a more trustworthy connection.

Comment: If the hashes are served over the same, untrusted connection, they could also be modified. Like you said though, HTTPS solves this problem as long as the user doesn't bypass any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest solve for this is to not just use HTTPS, but to arrange it so that the download is completed with a specific certificate that only the trusted server has and the client verifies.

This way it doesn't matter what methods are employed by attackers to ensure your download request ends up in the wrong server, requesting a compromised file and tricked by being told alter wrong hash; if the client has direct knowledge of the certificate that must be used then the sending server either has the correct cert (implies correct server) or it does not